# How do I fix a revoked root certificate (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, certificate

For several weeks now, Chrome has been reporting certificate revoked errors on major websites.

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www1.bac-assets.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED
```

It's getting to the point that I can't perform basic daily functions.  I get the same error if I try Edge, so it seems to be a Windows 10 system problem.  I've searched everywhere, and not found a solution, most sites suggest checking system clock, clearing cache, cookies, etc.  None of these solutions have worked.

I did find that I could look at the certificate chain, and it appears I have a revoked root certificate for **Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2** in the Chrome certificate chain (right click on the address bar, certificate.)

I found something to check mmc console, and there doesn't seem to be an issue if I look in the mmc console at root certificates (no obvious problem anyway.)

Anyone know how to fix this revoked certificate?  It's driving me crazy!  Help ??

[image: Certificate Chain]

[image: MMC console]

Edit:

bankofamerica.com  & tmobile.com

[image]

[image]

Comment: Serial number 4a538c28; Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.18363

Comment: I tried that that, and restart.  The test website works.  This one doesn't: https://www1.bac-assets.com/homepage/spa-assets/images/assets-images-global-logos-icon-ehl-white-CSX189e8f4c.svg    or this one   https://cdn.tmobile.com/content/dam/t-mobile/en-p/cell-phones/samsung/samsung-galaxy-s10/prism-black/Samsung-Galaxy-S10-Prism-Black-1-3x.jpg... both are 2ndary sites making main site mostly unusable

Comment: Added t-mobile and bankofamerica examples.... seems to be only script/html loading from 2nd sites now?  having trouble finding top level sites that are blocked... so re-installed sort of fixed it?  I've disabled my extensions, doesn't help.  This is a personal computer, no domain.

Comment: Incognito is the same behavior.  what is 1909?  I had both windows and chrome check for updates, both up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to fix this revoked certificate?

The certificate is not actually revoked.  Your system improperly believes it has been revoked.  You should remove `Entrust Root Certification Authority (G2)` from the certificate store, download [Entrust Root Certification Authority (G2)](https://www.entrust.com/resources/certificate-solutions/tools/root-certificate-downloads) directly from the root authority, and reinstall it. in question and reinstall it
You can validate the certificate is properly working by visiting [this](https://validg2.entrust.net/) test website.

**You should absolutely NOT disable "Check for server certificate revocation".**  The major reason you shouldn't disable that option is that it won't solve your problem, as the certificate was already in an invalid state.

The second reason you shouldn't disable that option is due to the fact it will make your system extremely insecure.  Certificate revocation is one of the primary security features of SSL/TLS certificates.

Comment: Simply deleting the certificate worked.  Perhaps it was corrupt, or in another store.

Comment: The bad certificate keeps getting restored!  Simply deleting it fixes things again... no idea where it's coming from, and why it's breaking things though.

Comment: I've updated to the latest version of windows10, and still having issues with this.  This bad certificate issue keeps coming back.

Comment: Sounds like persistent malware.  Even restoring the certificate shouldn’t be necessary since you never specifically went and uninstalled it.  If you are connected to a corporate network contact your Administrator (I forget the details of your case).

Comment: I eventually gave up and disabled the auto certificate updates, which seems to have resolved the problem, though not a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue for bankofamerica.com site.

I found in internet options, content, certificates, trusted root certificates. I had an entrust certificate that did not have a friendly name attached to it.

It was labelled Entrust Root Certificate Authority - G2. I had 2 of them one had a friendly name and the other did not. I deleted the one that did not have a friendly name and restarted computer.